# Database failure shuts down ActiveMQ windows service using JDBC persistence

Tags: windows, service, configuration, jdbc, activemq-classic

I have an ActiveMQ broker running as a Windows service. Its using *jdbcPersistenceAdapter* with Oracle data source and Oracle's Universal Connection Pooling (UCP).

When the database is down (due to network problems or scheduled maintenance), the ActiveMQ windows service shuts down completely. This, of course makes the broker unavailable even after the database is restored.

I have tried connection validation in UCP, DBCP with connection validation and even MySQL data source without any success. The service shuts down within 30 seconds of database failure (I believe this is because the default *cleanupInterval* is 30 seconds).

Is there a way to **prevent the windows service from shutting down** and make it wait for database availability?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my current configuration from activemq.xml:

```
<persistenceAdapter>
    <jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#oracle-ds"/>
</persistenceAdapter>

<bean id="oracle-ds" class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory" 
    factory-method="getPoolDataSource" p:URL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:amq" 
    p:connectionFactoryClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" 
    p:validateConnectionOnBorrow="true" p:user="appuser" p:password="userspassword" />
```

Comment: do you get the same behavior when using the journalPersistenceAdapterFactory?

Comment: Thanks for the tip @boday. I configured *journalPersistenceAdapterFactory* and got the same behavior, the windows service stops in 30 seconds. I used a new *persistenceFactory* with Oracle data store, instead of *persistenceAdapter*.

Answer (score 0):

generally, you should use a JDBC master/slave to support failover from another broker when the database becomes unavailable...

see http://activemq.apache.org/jdbc-master-slave.html

that said, there is a known issue with JDBC master/slave failover that was fixed in 5.6.0...

see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-1958